# How to write binary ZIP file received from CURL upload in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, lambda, serverless-framework

I would like to make my code save binary data uploaded via CURL
Here is CURL command I use: `curl --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --trace-ascii debugdump.txt --data-binary @test-files/small-test.zip http://localhost:8000/chrome`.
On the Node JS (receiving side) there is script that takes AWS Lambda event object and takes `event.body` property into this function:

#### handler.js

```
export default (async function run(event, context, callback) {

    //here event.body keeps the content of small-test.zip
    //logged content is encoded with \u0000 signs- take a look at second screenshot
    console.log(event);
    writeToDiskAndUnpackDocument(event.body);
}

function writeToDiskAndUnpackDocument(binaryFileContents) {
    //here I get binary content - take a look at second screenshot
    //logged content looks the same as displayed by linux command "cat small-test.zip"
    console.log(binaryFileContents); 
    //this command writes event.body to disk, but result file is not the same as that in curl command
    fs.writeFile('/tmp/document.zip', binaryFileContents,'binary');
}
```

The `document.zip` lands inside `tmp` folder, when I issue `cat document.zip` it looks different from the input file `test-files/small-test.zip`. I don't know why it differs. Here is the screenshot, at the top is original file, at the bottom is received file.
[image: comparison of sent and received file]

I am using serverless-offline to do developing of the solution.
How can I properly save this ZIP file on in Lambdas tmp (first my own linux laptop)?

#### Comparison of binary data in event object and in `writeToDiskAndUnpackDocument` argument:

[image: differences of binary content]

Comment: Yes it is good to get -1 without any explanation, thank you very much whoever did this and I wish same to you.

Answer (score 1):

I will avoid dealing with local filesystem when dealing with serverless, Why not use S3 to download your binary file?

If you still want to download a binary file and pipe it to filesystem,

```
request
  .get('http://example.com/doodle.png')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/doodle.png'))
```

It can download and get it to the filesystem.

**Reference:**

https://github.com/request/request

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to make requests, I want to receive requests (as in CURL example). And I am beginner with everything AWS, so I would like to omit upload to S3 because its another topic I would have to got to know.

Comment: They are differentiated with different HTTP verbs. Whatever CURL can do, request can also do. With reference to local file system, you need to think in a scalable way of small to any number of store. S3 can take care of that.

Comment: I tried to add more information to my question, because I wasn't clear enough and your answer does no answers to what I am having problem with.

Comment: Still request POST GET or whatever verb I will use does not resolve my problem. I want to receive HTTP calls, Github page of `request` says "Simplified HTTP request client. Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http calls." See? I want to receive call, not to make a call.